# Using the to_char function to format long numbers with thousands separators

Tags: postgresql, oracle, formatting, to-char

Using the `to_char` function, I can format my numbers with decimals and thousands separators easily enough.

```sql
to_char(number,'FML999G999G999D00')
```

However, it seems unnecessarily tedious to have to add all the extra groups just in case I have a long number before the decimal. I know that shorter numbers will be catered for, but is there a format which allows for indefinitely long numbers?

My main interest is in PostgreSQL, but I gather that Oracle uses the same function with nearly the same behaviour. I don’t know whether any other DBMS uses the `to_char` function.

Answer (score 2):

At least in Oracle, precision is at most 38, which means numbers can't be "indefinitely" long. The longest integer part format model (which you may, therefore, hard-code in all your calls to `to_number()`) is

```
99G999G999......G999
```

where there are 12 groups `G999` (each group is 3 digits, 3 * 12 = 36, plus the first two digits at the left end of the string = total 38 digits).

(Note - while `1e50`, or `power(10, 50)`, or in non-Oracle notation `10^50` or `10**50`, is a valid number in Oracle, converting it to a character string with `to_char()` with thousands separators throughout is not valid. Not sure about PostgreSQL.)

If you are creatively lazy like me, you will note that this string has length 50 (4 * 12 + 2); so you can do something like this:

```
with
  test_inputs (num) as (
    select 598475228744158.33 from dual union all
    select -3                 from dual union all
    select 0                  from dual union all
    select null               from dual union all
    select -0.4444444         from dual
  )
select num, to_char(num, 'FML' || rpad('99', 50, 'G999') || 'D00') as num_str
from   test_inputs
;

                 NUM NUM_STR        
-------------------- --------------------------------
  598475228744158.33 $598,475,228,744,158.33        
                  -3 -$3.00          
                   0 $.00             
            
          -0.4444444 -$.44
```

Most developers forget (or never learn) that the format model can be any expression that returns a character string - it doesn't have to be a literal.

With enough motivation, you can do much fancier things - like writing your own function that intercepts the format model and extends the digits-and-groups portion of the string to the maximum valid length, etc. (I imagine few people will have enough motivation for *that*, though.)

Comment: PostgreSQL is not that limited, and `numeric` is a binary coded decimal that can be up to 1GB in size. But the answer is the same: you have to write a pattern that is long enough to cater for your longest number.